# Deleting a specific key within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Thank you for stopping by. I'm a but confused in regards to my code. I've tried different variation but continue to not be able to just delete a single key from an array of obs. For example:

```
var cart = [];
var obj = {};
var newObj = {};

obj["mcdonald"] = "food"
obj["starbucks"] = "coffee"
newObj["new"] = "books"
newObj["old"] = "books"

cart.push(obj);
cart.push(newObj)
```

Now we want to remove just a single key. Let say for example just "new" key with value "books" from newObj object instead of the entire object. Every single time I get the entire object being deleted instead of just a single key. Can someone please tell me what I may be missing or where I'm going wrong. This is a homework I'm working on. I notice the test passes since we need to remove the item we place into the parameter but I want to be able to learn it the right way. Meaning, move a single key not the entire object.

```
function removeFromCart(itemName){
 for(var newArr in cart){
  if (cart.hasOwnProperty(newArr)) {
   var item = Object.keys(cart[newArr])[0]
   if (item === itemName) {
    var index = cart.indexOf(itemName)
    cart.splice(index, 1)
   } else {
    alert('That item is not in your cart.')
   }
  }
 }
 return cart
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `delete cart[itemName]` work?

Comment: @apokryfos Doesn't seem to pass the test if I did it that way. I removed var index and cart.splice(index, 1) and it says test failed since nothing was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better understand this, I'm going to create an example data structure:

```
var cart = [
  { "mcdonald": "food", "starbucks": "coffee" }, // obj
  { "new": "book", "old": "book" } // newObj
];
```

So now if I want to remove the item with key == 'new', it's easy to see that we need to iterate over all the objects in the array, and then delete any keys that match what we're looking for.

```
function removeItem(itemKey) {
  cart.forEach(function(obj) {
    delete obj[itemKey];
    return obj;
  });
}
```

I would also encourage you to write pure functions, as that will help you better understand (the coding intention) and debugging.